# How to nest a serializer?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to create an /api/info url that return various data on my application. It pulls data from various models and puts it together in one response. I got the following:

```
class SessionInfo(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        token = Token.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        is_admin = self.request.user.is_staff
        is_primary_owner = userprofile.primary_owner
        managers = userprofile.reports_to.all()
        man = ["test manager 1", "test manager 2"]
        pages = Page.objects.filter(published=True, show_in_menu=True)
        pages_output = JSONRenderer().render(PageSerializer(pages).data)
        content = {
            'user': {
                "username": str(self.request.user.username),
                "first_name": str(self.request.user.first_name),
                "last_name": str(self.request.user.last_name),
                "is_admin": is_admin,
                "is_primary_owner": is_primary_owner,
                "api_token": token.key,
                "timezone": 'blalala',
                "managers": man,
            },
            'license': {
                "plan" : "gold",
                "expiry_date" : "lol",
            },
            'feature_flags': {
                'billing_test': False,
            },
            'pages': { pages_output },
        }
        return Response(content)
```

However it doesn't properly serialize and render pages, making it an escaped string instead:

```
{
    "feature_flags": {
        "billing_test": false
    }, 
    "user": {
        "username": "test@user.com", 
        "first_name": "Test", 
        "last_name": "User", 
        "is_admin": true, 
        "managers": [
            "test manager 1", 
            "test manager 2"
        ], 
        "api_token": "08d1a5827da9a90e7746949ffd2e69e87c51b272", 
        "timezone": "blalala", 
        "is_primary_owner": false
    }, 
    "license": {
        "expiry_date": "lol", 
        "plan": "gold"
    }, 
    "pages": [
        "[{\"id\": 1, \"title\": \"Trololol\"}, {\"id\": 2, \"title\": \"NEW pages\"}]"
    ]
}
```

if I use directuly use pages_output = PageSerializer(pages) I get:

```
<webapp_api_v1.serializers.PageSerializer object at 0x10a0d8f90> is not JSON serializable
```

How can I make a serializer properly nest within my constructed response? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with pages_output =  PageSerializer(pages).data and changing 'pages': pages_output,